# Can we integrate napster in a .net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can we integrate napster in a .net website? If so please suggest any documentation to refer to.
Thanks.

Comment: Napster... wow that takes me back :)

Answer (score 3):

Napster doesn't have a public API, so there is no legitimate, supported method for accessing it from other services. However, the search protocol is simple and has been documented to a limited extent [here](http://blog.song-list.net/2006/12/02/napster-music-webservices/).

Obviously there is no guarantee that this will still work a day, week, month or year from now, and you'll need to write your own .NET wrapper code. But it is at least somewhat possible.

Answer (score 2):

Napster released an API shortly after this question was asked, if it still applies.

http://developer.napster.com/